# How to calculate heap fragmenation statistics using heap dumps

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory, fragmentation

Does anyone knows if there is any tool out there to calculate the heap fragmentation using heap dumps?

Comment: Are you using a collector which has a problem with fragmentation?

Comment: Does the mat toot provide fragmentation statistics? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

I have a tool to visualize the heap (http://bobah.net/d4d/tools/cpp-heapmap) but it consumes the list of {op;address;size} triplets, not a raw heap dump. You can use it to visually estimate how bad the heap is. In some cases it's just enough. It's malloc interceptor would obviously not fit for Java app, but the UI does not care where numbers come from and would display ones from any source.

But let's assume we are able build a heap map from the dump (I'm sure someone will answer here how exactly). The main part of the problem is to calculate fragmentation curve F(s), s - target allocation size. F(s) - the ratio of (total_free_space/s),  to number of blocks of size s which can actually be allocated considering particular heap layout.

Once the F(s) is built, one can integrate it in the interval from 1 to S (total heap size) to have a single number representing the heap fragmentation or usage efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

The [IBM Garbage Collection and Memory Analyzer](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/gcmv/) is excellent for that sort of thing and is free.